# is some files are missing after installing sanity.io?

Tags: next.js, sanity

I have created a project portfolio with the hep of code with harry using sanity.io but it looks like some files and folders are missing in my portfolio folder like yarn.lock , tconfig.json etc. I can't get why is this so?. I am following every step in my set up:

[image]

I am curios to know the reason why that was happening ?